# Borderless window appears sometimes when running Visual Studio 2019

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Recently, when starting Visual Studio 2019 on my laptop, a grey borderless window started appearing.

On the taskbar, the window is grouped under Visual Studio. I can close the window, but it will reappear when starting another instance of Visual Studio.

Using Spy++ I can see the window title is "Program Manager", which I have not been able to find any information about, except that it was a program in windows 3.11.

If anyone has any suggestion which setting in Visual Studio makes this window pop up, or how to permanently disable it I would greatly appreciate it.

A composited screenshot for extra clarity: 
[image]

Comment: I didn't see this behavior on my laptop and I have VS 2019 too.

Comment: I'm sure it's some kind of setting or perhaps something specific to my projects, it's just not clear for me where it comes from.

Comment: It turns out it's related to the Code Coverage results window in Visual Studio. I haven't found a solution yet though.